# Play Framework 1.2.4 : Custom jars modified on "play dependencies" command

Tags: playframework, dependency-management

I'm trying to specify custom dependencies in a local folder, and my *dependencies.yml* file looks like this:

```
require:
   - play
   - my.group -> module-1 0.0.1
   - my.group -> module-2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   - my.other.group -> module-1 1.0-alpha
   - my.other.group -> module-2 1.2.0

repositories:
   - jars:
      type:     local
      artifact: "${application.path}/jars/[module]-[revision].jar"
      contains:
         - my.group -> *
         - my.other.group -> *
```

I'm having two issues:

1: The jars with a group ID matching that of my Play module do not get copied. Running `play deps --verbose` shows that they were found (`found my.group#module-1;0.0.1 in jars in [default]`) but the "Installing resolved dependencies" section adds a strange path that's different than the others. While the jars from other group IDs are listed as `lib/module-2-1.2.0.jar`, the jars from my module are shown as `modules/lib -> <path/to/play/proj>/lib`. So although it looks like the dependencies resolution was executed successfully, those specific jars don't get copied.

If I change *dependencies.yml* to this format:

```
require:
   - play
   - my.group.module-1 -> module-1 0.0.1
   - my.group.module-2 -> module-2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
   - my.other.group -> module-1 1.0-alpha
   - my.other.group -> module-2 1.2.0

repositories:
   - jars:
      type:     local
      artifact: "${application.path}/jars/[module]-[revision].jar"
      contains:
         - my.group.module-1 -> *
         - my.group.module-2 -> *
         - my.other.group -> *
```

where I include the module name in the declaration of the "contains" section, then the jars get copied successfully. Which leads to my second problem:

2: When I run `play deps`, it seems like my jars are either modified when they're copied, or they're being pulled down from some older cached version. I was getting inconsistent behavior when running my program, as if old code was being used. I did a `ls -al` on both the lib and jars folders to compare, and the file size is much smaller on the copied jars than on the originals.

Any ideas what's happening here? I've been able to work around it by copying jars manually, but I have no idea why there's this inconsistency between jars from certain groups.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but has the issue been resolved? This is my deps file. Works for me:

require:
    - play -> play 1.2.4
    - provided -> joda-time 2.0

repositories:
    -    provided:
       type:       local
       descriptor: "${play.path}/[module]/conf/dependencies.yml"
       artifact:   "${play.path}/jar/[module]-[revision].jar"
       contains:
         - provided -> *

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be solved using this command:

```
play dependecies --clearcache
```

The --clearcache empties the Ivy cache. If you don't clear the cache, play will not check for newer versions in the repository that you configured.